# How to save session counts and retrieve the number of user access

Tags: codeigniter, session

I would like to know how to save the number of times a user access a webpage and return the session count to the user 
Eg
A user opens his user profile on a web page and would be able to see

Users number of access: 20times.

I have created the page with Codeigniter and created a table in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

But I don't know how to save the number of times the user has accessed the webpage

Comment: do you mean how many times he logged in? or how many page reloads user made?

Comment: I mean how many page reload the user makes